# Direction of polarization in dielectrics

Tags: electrostatics, dielectric, dipole

Our teacher just taught us polarization in dielectric materials. I have some doubts that he wasn't able to clear.

1. Is the direction of polarization, for any non-linear dielectric, in the direction of net electric field?
2. Polarization basically arises because of the electric field applied by us externally, then why is it's magnitude directly proportional to the net electric field? Shouldn't it's magnitude be proportional to just the applied electric field?

Comment: Consider the quadratic case
\begin{equation*}
P_{k}=\varepsilon _{klm}^{(2)}E_{l}E_{m}
\end{equation*}
In general, depending on the tensor $\varepsilon _{klm}^{(2)}$, $\mathbf{P}$
will not be along $\mathbf{E}$. Secondly the magnitude of $\mathbf{P}$ will
be proportional to $|\mathbf{E}|^{2}$ and not to $|\mathbf{E}|$.

Comment: The E you are writing in the equation is the net electric field or the applied electric field? @Urgje

Comment: Depending on the situation it can be either. But still both, linear and non-linear, polarisation need not be along E.

Comment: A molecule in the dielectric cannot not know which part of the "E" field is external, and which part is due to the polarization of the other molecules. It's all "E" to him.

Answer (score 0):

Sir James Clerk Maxwell did not exclude that polarization and applied electric field were in different directions. See his

> A Treatise on Electricity and Magnetism

page [63-64 [61-62](https://archive.org/details/electricandmagne01maxwrich/page/n100/mode/2up?q=Amp%C3%A8re&view=theater)

[image: Peculiar features]
...
[image: electric energy]
[image: angle between E and D]